# How to take backup of marklogic database while upgrading from CentOS to RHEL

Tags: centos, marklogic, rhel6, marklogic-8

We want to move our cluster server from centos to RHEL. How can we ensure that Marklogic database is backed up and in the process we don't loose any data. 
Do we need to backup on external data storage device?

Answer (score 1):

I guess keeping backup on an external storage drive will be a safe idea. Are you planning to block all the operations on you database? If not, you need to consider updates on database during the migration from CentOS to RHEL also.

Comment: Hi Ankit,
 I guess you mean planning to back all operations instead of block, in that case my answer is yes.We have executable ready. Will taking backup of each host in cluster and then restoring them will do? I guess we need to tak backup of /var/opt/Marklogic only?

Comment: I think rather than backing up folder you should take backup of each database you require and then copy those backups onto a external drive. Later in time you can restore those backups on your Updated RHEL environment.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, RHEL and CentOS database backups will be binary compatible. I'd suggest creating a second cluster running RHEL, and using database backup/restore to migrate data. What Ankit means though is what you do with updates happening during that backup/restore. You could consider putting the CentOS databases in read-only, then start backup, do restore on RHEL, and flip over to the RHEL which means db updates can happen again. You could run a test with backup/restore first as well..

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. What I understand from the reply is that
1.) I will create database backup from old ML Server cluster on external device 
2. And then restore on RHEL6.5 using restore feature after creating new cluster.

There is one more question, do we need to rework on App Servers? or isn't there any way we can copy whole of cluster objects into our new cluster.

Comment: Not sure about first part of your question. @grtjn can tell better about this. About app servers, you can use Marklogic Configuration Manager (8002 port) to export all you app servers.

*A humble request - Do not ask separate questions in comments as these question won't be easily accessible to other community members. May be you can mark this as resolved and ask other questions separately.*

Comment: I would also recommend reaching out to support at MarkLogic (assuming you are entitled to production support). They are there to help with cases like this as well.